# Slick carosel is not working inside Project file

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have previously used Owl carousel for my website , now I changed to slick carousel for slider in my website for [NATA coaching center in Chennai](https://www.neramclasses.com). The problem is am not getting the slider working and i don't know what mistake am doing... All images are in flex-column but I want it to look like vertical slider. Here am attaching how i want it to be.

[image: UI design showing vertical image slider]

vertical slider using slick , Here is the sample [Codepen](https://codepen.io/chinhphan099/pen/MebgmP)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.items').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3
    });
    });
```

```css
.contact-card {
  background-color: #88206D;
  border: solid 2px #fff;
  border-radius: 21px;
  min-height: 406px;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 6px 6px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 6px 6px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 6px 6px 9px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#google-icon img {
  height: 44px;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 22px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53);
  -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53);
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.google-review {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.col-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row contact-card">
      <div class="map col-5" id="map"></div>
      <div class="offset-2 image-scroll"></div>
      <div class="map-des col-3 text-white my-auto pt-4" id="m-des"></div>

      <!-- i struggle in this part -- >

                <!-- google reviews -->
      <div class="col-1 text-center">
        <div id="google-icon">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/nknMt4k/search.png" class="google-icon">
        </div>


        <div class="side-star">
          <p class="google-review text-nowrap">
            <strong>Google Review</strong>
          </p>
          <div class="five-star d-flex flex-column">

            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-star"></i>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div></div>
      
<!-- struggling here -->
      
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">

            <div class="items">
              <div><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190720/gallery/preview/02_o_car.jpg"></div>
              <div><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190715/gallery/preview/03_r_car.jpg"></div>
              <div><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190714/gallery/preview/04_g_car.jpg"></div>
              <div><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190714/gallery/preview/04_g_car.jpg"></div>
              <div><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190714/gallery/preview/04_g_car.jpg"></div>
              <div><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190714/gallery/preview/04_g_car.jpg"></div>
              <div><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190714/gallery/preview/04_g_car.jpg"></div>
          </div>



          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. You need to apply CSS also

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.row', '.container').slick({
        verticalScrolling: true,
        vertical: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
    -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}

button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}



.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container .item {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

.row .item img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.slick-no-slide .slick-track {
    width: 100% !important;
    text-align: center;
    transform: inherit !important;
}

.slick-no-slide .slick-slide {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}

.slick-list {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slick-dots {
    text-align: center;
}

.slick-dots li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.slick-dots li button {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin: 0 5px;
    font-size: 0;
    background-color: grey;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
}

.slick-dots .slick-active button {
    background-color: black;
}

.slick-prev {
    left: 10px;
    background: url("data:image/png;base64,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") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.slick-next {
    right: 10px;
    background: url("data:image/png;base64,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") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

.slick-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 48%;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 0;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class='item'><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190720/gallery/preview/02_o_car.jpg"></div>
            <div class='item'><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190715/gallery/preview/03_r_car.jpg"></div>
            <div class='item'><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190714/gallery/preview/04_g_car.jpg"></div>
            <div class='item'><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190714/gallery/preview/04_g_car.jpg"></div>
            <div class='item'><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190714/gallery/preview/04_g_car.jpg"></div>
            <div class='item'><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190714/gallery/preview/04_g_car.jpg"></div>
            <div class='item'><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxfq3iotg/image/upload/v1565190714/gallery/preview/04_g_car.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick.js'></script>
```

Removed `div.items` since it doesn't had any style and don't cover `div.item`. It's parent must be `div.slick` because you provided to apply for that `div` in JavaScript. 
url present in `.slick-next` and `.slick-prev` is very large. You can find your own buttons image and add to it.

Comment: I forget to link main.js... Am sorry for the lame question